# Neo4j Find alternative shortest paths between nodes

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, shortest-path

How do I find multiple distinct short paths between 2 nodes in a graph with 7.5M nodes and 20M relationships?
We want a feature similar to how google maps shows other alternative routes.

problems with:
Dijkstra, shortestPath and allShortestPaths:
Only returns the shortest path or paths with the shortest length.

Yen's k shortest paths:
Absurdly slow on a big graph

Iterate over list of numbers 0-10 and call allShortestPaths with minimum number of length of i:
Absurdly slow on a big graph

Comment: You are numbering weighted and unweighted algorithms like it doesn't make a difference. For the weighted variant, probably the GDS yen's k-shortest is the best option.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, because when I tested it it would take 2 mins to find a couple of paths with length of 4-5, while finding paths with length of 6 was impossible.

Comment: @TomažBratanič there is no weight in my graph

Comment: @TomažBratanič what do you think of my provided solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I figured that filtering/blacklisting for certain relationships that already has been used for another path could work. However, when I tried this in practice i noticed that filtering after running allShortestPaths wasn't a viable solution. After this I figured doing allShortestPaths mulitple times and when a path is found I could rename the type to currentTypeName_TEMP, then rename it after again.

To find multiple distinct paths, this could be done with an algorithm shown on the picture, and given the effectiveness of allShortestPaths, this will not be that computational or time intensive (dotted lines means found relationships).

[image]

EDIT:
turns out this is rather difficult in cypher, since it is very restricive in nature, we ended up writing a plugin, where we made a hack of dijkstra where it takes N of the shortest paths.